# Python Requests with API Key in header

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I've been working on this for the last 10 hours and haven't made any head way.  I'm hoping someone can point out where I went wrong.  I'm trying to connect with a swagger API.

I am given:

- url
- api-key
- Security Scheme Type
- Header Parameter Name

The body will carry my payload, and the header is supposed to have my api-key.  I've created a few variations of this but I've got `400` code responses each time.

```
r = requests.post(Url, data=payload, headers={"Authorization": API_Key})

r = requests.post(Url, data=payload, headers={"Header Parameter Name": API_Key})

r = requests.post(Url, data=payload, headers={"Authorization":{"Header Parameter Name": API_Key}})
```

These 3 requests give me:
Response [401]

```
r = requests.post(loginUrl, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Authorization": API_Key})
```

gives me:
Response [401]

```
r = requests.post(loginUrl, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Header Parameter Name": API_Key})
```

gives me:

```
"message" : "Unrecognized token 'ship_to_address': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 17]",
  "code" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
```

Comment: Show the curl command that swagger returns, please

Comment: What is the body of the 400 response, will often give you a hint as to why it's a bad request.

Comment: I only get <Response [401]>
if I add 'Content-Type': 'application/json' I get:
<Response [422]>
{
  "message" : "Unrecognized token 'cancellation_policy': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 21]",
  "code" : "INVALID_REQUEST"

Comment: With another client (example postman) ...can you?

Comment: Do you have the swagger endpoint you can share with us?

Comment: I was able to get in via postman program.  Im currently trying to reverse engineer it but stuck on getting my payload dictionary converted to json.

Comment: I can copy the payload string from the postman program over to my code and it does work. But I still cant manage to convert what I have to a json format.

Comment: Ive tried newPayload = json.pumps(payload) as well as 
r = requests.post(loginUrl, json=payload, headers=payloadheader)